# PHP PECL EXTENSION INSTALL DREAMHOST ERROR: 'phpize' failed

Tags: php, oauth, pecl, phpize

I am trying to install the PECL extension Oauth on DreamHost.  I used:

```
$ pear install pecl/oauth-1.2.3
```

I get back:

> ERROR: 'phpize' failed

In the DreamHost Wiki it says:

> If any installation requires you to run 'phpize', just specify the full path to your desired version of PHP. For example:
>   /usr/local/php55/bin/phpize
>   /usr/local/php56/bin/phpize

I try to run phpize and I get back:

Make sure that you run `usr/local/php56/bin/phpize` in the top level source directory of the module.

I am very confused.  Can anyone help?

Comment: It's sound DreamHost turn NightmareHost.